# Reformat all links in Dreamweaver using regular expression?

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a long document with links in the usual format i.e.:

```
<a href="http://www.somelink.com/tosomewhere">Link Text</a>
```

I need to replace all links like this with the following:

```
[Link Text](http://www.somelink.com/tosomewhere)
```

Or, ideally:

```
[Link Text](http://www.somelink.com/tosomewhere "Link Text")
```

Is this possible somehow with Dreamweaver regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

Go to Find and Replace. Enter the following:

Search:

```
<a href="(.*)">(.*)</a>
```

Replace:

```
[$2]($1)
```

Check "use regular expression box".

Click "Replace all".